# If $[F:E]$ is prime, then $F=E(a)$ for any $a\in F\setminus E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Assume that $E\subset F$ and that $E$ and $F$ are fields. Also, say $[E:F]=p$, where $p$ is a prime.  If $a$ is any element of $F\setminus E$.  Show that $F=E(a)$.

I'm pretty unsure of how to approach this.

Answer (score 7):

Degrees are multiplicative:
$$
[F : E] = [F : E(a)][E(a) : E].
$$
See Proposition 1.20 of [Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html) for a proof. What can you say about $[E(a) : E]$ now?